# How to write/overwrite in csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

So I created this database and I am trying to enter the ID of the person so I can update the persons surgery. New to coding and python but not sure how to get this as the first half works but the 2nd half just deletes the whole database. Its difficult because I know how to add rows but not sure how to edit/add certain words to a certain row. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import csv

id = input('Enter the ID of the person which surgery you want to edit: ')
with open('Treatment.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for col in csv_reader:
        for row in col:
            if row == id:
                print(col)

surgeryedit = input('Update Surgery: ')
with open('Treatment', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    txt = surgeryedit
    next(new_file)
    for col in csv_reader:
        for row in col:
            if id == row:
                csv_writer.write(row[2],txt)
```

[Here's the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAaUr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maintatining CSV files, data in Python i suggest you using **Pandas** library. When you get familliar with Pandas, you will see how useful that library is. For example, this is how you can edit certain field in your CSV data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read.csv("Treatment.csv")
```

Then you make a `pandas.DataFrame` object, to quickly edit your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now you can easily get any column, row or field from your data, just by using slicing and indexing.
For example how to replace any person's data:

```
df[id[3]] = new_person_data
```

There are many well written tutorials, and documentation, so here I won't explain you what I've written, I've done this to show you how useful Pandas is and how fast you can access data using it. I strongly recommend learning both NumPy and Pandas as basics for data management with Python.